# Adding formula via VBA throws Runtime-Exception

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a formula to a cell via VBA but just getting *Runtime-Exception 1004* without further information.

```
Cells(4, 3).Formula = "=IF('Mustermann, Max'!C13="""";"""";""impacting team targets"")"
```

Is there something wrong with my formula?

Answer (score 1):

Need to use Comma instead of Semikolon.

```
Cells(4, 3).Formula = "=IF('Mustermann, Max'!C13="""","""",""impacting team targets"")"
```